# SonarQube and Github, Travis CI

Tags: github, sonarqube, travis-ci

Is there any way to programmatically check say, using the GitHub API or some API for Travis CI, if a particular project on GitHub or Travis CI uses SonarQube?

Also apart from SonarQube what other program analysis tools do people usually use?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to see how many open source projects on GitHub use static program analysis tools.

Answer (score 0):

Neither GitHub API nor Travis CI API will be able to provide you with such information - simply because code analysis tools/services are third-party systems that are not built-in features of GitHub or Travis CI.

If you want to `"see how many open source projects on GitHub use static program analysis tools"`, then you would have to browse the source code of each repository to discover some facts that might give you this information (like for instance looking into the `.travis.yml` file). But because there's no built-in/standard feature on that topic, this would be extremely difficult to correctly achieve this goal IMO.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to look for travis.yml files in the project and then search for the keyword 'sonarqube' in the file?

Comment: For projects that use SonarQube.com service, indeed this would probably give you a good idea (even though they are not obliged to use the SonarQube.com Travis Add-on).